# close networking hardware in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, networking

I have an iOS app and we have a regular tracking network update which is using alot of power. We are looking for various ways of reducing this. Is it possible to power down netowrking hardware quicker? as in decrease the additional period of time they are turned on in anticipation of more work ?

Thanks

Feras A.